# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' dataframe list map

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe

I am trying to map data using a list instead of a string

If the number is inside the list, then map it to `xyz`

Any way I can do this using a list?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'INDICATOR': ['0001024561', 'B', '0001024561', 'D'], 'VALUE': [10, 9, 8, 7]})

company_dict = {[
    '0001024561',
    '0001024576',
    ]: 'xyz'}

df['NEW_VALUE'] = df['INDICATOR'].map(company_dict)

print(df)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IICU:

Use dict

```
company_dict = {'0001024561':'xyz','0001024576':'xyz'}
df['NEW_VALUE'] = df['INDICATOR'].map(company_dict)
```

Using list

```
lst=['0001024561','0001024576']
df.loc[df['INDICATOR'].isin(lst),'NEW_VALUE']='xyz'
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting answer, could you please press the up arrow so that people seeking answers can confidently use solution?